# How to customize a UIAlert View Popup

Tags: uialertview

I was wondering how to create and customize a UIAlert View Popup, like ones in popular games such as Angry Birds or Cut the Rope. 
I just want to say can you please rate my game and have 3 options to choose from. I want to design it so the text font and color changes and the background color can change to a picture or something? Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your UIAlert is short enough to fit without the inherent scroll bar of longer text, then this will work:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title Here" message:@Message here..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];

((UILabel*)[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
((UILabel*)[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try subclassing UIAlertView using [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html) tutorial. Such UIAlertViews can be achieved with either a subclass of UIAlertView or by creating a separate view all together that simulates the look and feel of a UIAlertView.

Comment: UIAlertView can not be subclassed. The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified. From UIAlertView Class Reference. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: //Sorry, Jailbroken developer here.